# How do I do an HTTPGet to a custom controller method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, httprequest, dbcontext

What is the best way to do an httpget request to the custom controller method GetTestInfoByTestTypeID.  Please find below my client app, API controller, model and dbcontext.  The TestInfo and TestInfo/ID request work, but the GetTestInfoByTestTypeID method does not work.

**Client**

```
   request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
   // request.RequestUri = new Uri(ConstantsCS.c_BaseURL + "/TestIT/TestInfo"); WORKS
   // request.RequestUri = new Uri(ConstantsCS.c_BaseURL + "/TestIT/TestInfo/4"); WORKS
      request.RequestUri = new Uri(ConstantsCS.c_BaseURL + "/TestIT/TestInfo/GetTestInfoByTestTypeID/4"); //DOES NOT WORK

   HttpResponseMessage responsemsg = await client.SendAsync(request);
   if (responsemsg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
   }
```

**API Controller method:**

```
#region "TestIT/Testinfo/GetTestInfoByTestTypeID/1"
        [HttpGet("{TestTypeId}", Name = "GetTestInfoByTestTypeID")]
        public IEnumerable<TestInfo> GetTestInfoByTestTypeID([FromRoute] int TestTypeId)
        {
            try
            {
                List<TestInfo> tstinfoIn = _context.TestInfo.ToList();
                List<TestTypeInfo> tsttypinfoIn = _context.TestTypeInfo.ToList();

                List<TestInfo> tstinfoCombo = new List<TestInfo>();

                tstinfoCombo = tstinfoIn.Select(c => new TestInfo()
                {
                    TestId = c.TestId,
                    TestShortDescription = c.TestShortDescription,
                    TestLongDescription = c.TestLongDescription,
                    TestTypeId = c.TestTypeId,
                    TestTypeInfos = GetTestTypeInfo(tsttypinfoIn, c.TestTypeId)
                }).ToList();

                tstinfoCombo = tstinfoCombo
                    .Where(x => x.TestTypeId == TestTypeId)
                    .Select(x => new TestInfo()
                {
                    TestId = x.TestId,
                    TestShortDescription = x.TestShortDescription,
                    TestLongDescription = x.TestLongDescription,
                    TestTypeId = x.TestTypeId,
                    TestTypeInfos = x.TestTypeInfos
                }).ToList();

                return tstinfoCombo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

**TestInfo Model:**

```
namespace TestITWebService.Model
{
    public partial class TestInfo
    {
        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public string TestShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string TestLongDescription { get; set; }
        public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TestTypeInfo> TestTypeInfos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DBContext:**

```
#region "TestInfo"
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestInfo>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.TestId);

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.TestShortDescription)
                    .HasName("IX_TestInfo")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.TestId).HasColumnName("TestID");

                entity.Property(e => e.TestLongDescription)
                    .HasMaxLength(150)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.TestShortDescription)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.TestTypeId).HasColumnName("TestTypeID");
            });
            #endregion
```

Comment: Please edit your question with your code *as text*.  Please don't give us screenshots of code.  See:  [Why not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Removed images and replaced with code.

Comment: update code to only show the parts which are important.... way to many actions if its about GetTestInfoByTestTypeID  only, current code is a mess on SO please update so its readable.

Comment: Can anyone share come constructive input on how to get the controller to return only the test info for a particular test type id?  Do I have to pass the test type as a parameter?  Any examples would be appreciated.